# What is the fastest algorithm to find the minimum difference between pairs of numbers in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to find two numbers whose difference is minimum in O(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669922/is-it-possible-to-find-two-numbers-whose-difference-is-minimum-in-on-time)

For example, in `[4, 2, 7, 11, 8]`, the algorithm should return `abs(7-8) = 1`.

The brute force way will be O(n<sup>2</sup>) and sorting will give O(nlogn). Is there more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: If the values are integers and are in some fixed range, you could use a radix sort to do the sorting in O(n) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think sorting and comparing is going to be your best bet. Something like:

```
function minDiff( arr ) {
    var min,
        temp,
        initDiff = false,
        arr = arr.sort( function(a, b){return a-b} ),
        last = arr.length - 1,
        i;

    for ( i = 0; i < last; i++ ) {

        if ( !initDiff ) {            
            min = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
            initDiff = true;
        } else {            
            temp = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];

            if ( temp < min ) {            
                min = temp;            
            }            
        }
    }

    return min; 
}

var myArr = [ 1, 8, 5, 96, 20, 47 ],
    min = minDiff( myArr );

console.log( min ); // 3
```

Comment: Soooo... what is the complexity here and do you think it can get better (than O(nlogn))? That is the OP's question

Answer (score 2):

A similar question here - [Is it possible to find two numbers whose difference is minimum in O(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669922/is-it-possible-to-find-two-numbers-whose-difference-is-minimum-in-on-time) .  It appears to be O(nlogn).

This page may give [useful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_uniqueness_problem) background info too.

Comment: The answers are so bad :(.  Element Uniqueness is cancer.  Hash hash hash!

Comment: Hmm, Ok, Why is Element Uniqueness cancer? And by "hash" you mean...?  BTW, what's your PL of choice :) ?