# Smallest difference between 2 elements from 2 arrays in linear time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I was wondering if there is a solution which takes O(n+m) to the following standard problem:

Given two arrays of integers, compute the pair of values (one value in each array) with the smallest (non-negative) difference.

Example:

```
Input : A[] = {l, 3, 15, 11, 2}
        B[] = {23, 127, 235, 19, 8} 
Output : 3  the pair (11, 8)
```

I know that if you use sorting, you can achieve the solution in O(NLOG(N)). Is there a solution that does not use sorting and which is linear? if there isn't, can we prove that there is none?

Thanks

Comment: Without additional assumptions about your range, can you even do this for a single array? [This post suggests not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669922/is-it-possible-to-find-two-numbers-whose-difference-is-minimum-in-on-time), unless you're talking about quantum/nonstandard computation models

Comment: I am pretty convinced we cannot. I am curious though to know if there is a proof about that, like with the comparative sorting lower bound.

Comment: If you're asking about a proof for a n+m lower-bound on this problem, then https://cs.stackexchange.com would be a much better place to ask the question. EDIT: Nevermind, the question linked by @kcsquared has a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Under the algebraic decision tree model, `O((m+n) log (m+n))` is the best you can do without limits on the range or extra allowable operations. This is at least as hard as testing whether A and B are disjoint, so you can use the same tactics as for proving the comparison sorting lower bound. For a concrete reference, the [proof by Ben-Or](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800061.808735) that testing whether two sets of length `n` are disjoint takes `Omega(n log n)` time (based on decision tree size) applies here by reduction.

Comment: Awsome thanks! that is what i was looking for.